# Illustrator Blend Tool not matching two paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

[image]

So I'm trying to create a stroke out of an S, and am using the normal blend tool trick to get a path down the middle but all I'm getting are these off lines that only start and end in the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blending gives often unexpected results if the blended paths have different amount of nodes or they are distributed differently. An example:

[image]

In the left there's 2 paths which are separated from a S. In the middle there's a succesful midline generation with blending. In the right there's an unsuccesful attempt after editing a little one of the paths. The halves have radically different node distributions.

You can try the following alternative tricks:

1) Offset path

2) give to one of the disassembled halves a half-width stroke and disassemble it

Comment: Ah yes that must be it. Was driving me crazy. Thanks!